# JSP and Javascript Cancel button not working

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

My cancel button does not work properly. It has the same behaviour as 'OK', it submits the page, and I want that the button does nothing.

Here is the code:

JS:

```
function showConfirmProcessamento(){    

            var msg = '';

                msg = 'calculo.param.confirmProcess';

                if (confirm(msg))
                    document.forms[0].reqCode.value='inative';  
                else
                    return false;


            return true;
        }
```

With my JSP Code:

```
 <html:link onclick="return showConfirmProcessamento();"   
page="/recSelf.do?reqCode=inative&amp;idRef=${tipo.idRefTipo}&amp;idConf=${beanSelf.idConf}">                                                                                           
</html:link>
```

Comment: what do you think this does?  if (showConfirm(msg))

Comment: @Stultuske my bad. edited.

Comment: ok, and what does 'confirm(msg)' do? is this a local function you have? is it linked to Window?

Comment: @Stultuske Ehm, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp 

Anyway, the question is what _not working_ means, i.e. what Wiz expects his code to do (or not do).

Comment: @Wiz I think `preventDefault()` is what you are looking for: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp - use it in the `else` branch of your `if` statement.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek thanks for your reply. My cancel button is doing the same as the Ok button, this means that he submits the page on the 2 buttons.

Comment: @Wiz for both cases, you set the same page as "goTo", is that what you mean by "does the same"?

Comment: @Stultuske yes... If  showConfirmProcessamento is true, the page should be loaded, if I click on Cancel, the page should be not submitted... but this is not happening.

Comment: well, you code it to happen in each case, what did you expect would happen? try putting the routing to the new page in the if - block

Comment: @Stultuske I thinkc I cannot put on JS script, because I have parameters defined on the page... idRef=${tipo.idRefTipo}

Comment: and you can't possibly pass those as parameters to the function because .... ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181066/discussion-between-wiz-and-stultuske).

Comment: @Stultuske and how can I put the parameters on JSP?
<html:link onclick="return executar(${tipo.idRefTipoReclamacao, beanSelf.idConfCalComissao});";

I'm getting an error.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek it does not work... if I click cancel, the page is submitted too.